# Not getting response from URL in volley but working in postman

Tags: java, android

**Introduction -**

I am trying to get json response from a external url. it does not require any special auth or header. we can just put it on as a url in web browser and get the response. but i am getting error in volley jsonrequest.

**URL -**
https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftyStockWatch.json

**Error i am getting in Volley -**

com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

**Volley Request -**

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest =
new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                      "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftyStockWatch.json",
                      null,
                      new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                         @Override
                         public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                         Log.i("TAG","response : " + response);
                         }
                      },
                      new Response.ErrorListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         Log.i("TAG","error : " + error);
                         }
                      });
queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

**Edit -**

The GET Request code that is being sent in Postman is -

```
GET
/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/juniorNiftyStockWatch.json HTTP/1.1
Host: www.nseindia.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6fd9baa2-9313-a592-fff4-445b3c5e25d2
```

*This might be helpful to suggest me why i am unable to get the same response in volley as in postman.*

I was wandering as i just put a GET request in postman with the URL, i get the response. but why i am not getting same response from the volley ?

Comment: Though there are few possible solutions for your requirement, but if you can say what is your exact requirment, it might be more helpful. I think, your problem can be solved using an interface, but still it would be great if you could mention exactly what you are trying to achieve instead of how you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I know this is far-fetched, but did you specify the `android.permission.INTERNET` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? And if you've done that, check that the device you're using for testing, can actually browse the internet.

Comment: @Sagar Nayak I am facing the same issue. Did you resolved this? .If yes can you tell me how to resolve this  ..

Comment: @fazil I didn't find any solution to access this API. this might use some cookies to validate so i am unable to access this from mobile. the alternative would be to just use direct dom parsing. i directly accessed the web page from mobile and parsed the required data.

Answer (score 0):

You inserted this tag on AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If not, insert it and try again.

if yes, your request headers on postman is the SAME on volley ?

Please post your request headers from volley for more information.

Comment: i would like to inform that i have done the permission in manifest. if i am testing this with any other url the same code is giving me response. i am facing the problem for this url only. there is no header that i am using in postman. i just select the GET request and put the url. that's it. i dont add any other header. you can just put this url in browswr and you will get a response.